# How do I programmatically disable "Connectivity Checking"?

Tags: 18.04, gsettings

I just installed Ubuntu 18.04 and going through all my dotfile-scripts to properly configure Ubuntu automatically as much as possible. Looping through gsettings I was able to configure most settings as I want them but I haven't found anything in gsettings related to "Connectivity Checking" which is new in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (at least not included in 16.04 LTS).

I can turn off Connectivity Checking through `Settings -> Privacy` but how can I do this programmatically? Just uninstall `network-manager-config-connectivity-ubuntu`? I was able to turn off other privacy settings through gsettings.

Viewing the file list of this package at https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/all/network-manager-config-connectivity-ubuntu/filelist indicates that there is just one settings file (`/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf`) but it does not show any possibility to enable/disable the feature.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**UPDATE 2022**: Please note that - even though this answer was accepted - the internal conf file shouldn't be edited manually according the the comment by thaller. The mentioned solution is:
Adding a config file to the /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d directory - [Documentation](https://developer-old.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/NetworkManager.conf.html):

> you can add additional .conf files to the /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d
> directory. These will be read in order, with later files overriding
> earlier ones.

Alternatively using D-Bus: `busctl --system set-property org.freedesktop.NetworkManager /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager org.freedesktop.NetworkManager ConnectivityCheckEnabled "b" 0`

(Haven't tested those options myself)

**Original Answer**:
There is a flag in the file `/var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager-intern.conf` that is set to false if you disable the setting in the UI:

```
[connectivity] 
.set.enabled=false
```

You can use the tool [`crudini`](http://www.pixelbeat.org/programs/crudini/) to set the flag using the command line or a script:

```
sudo crudini --set /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager-intern.conf "connectivity" ".set.enabled" "false"
```

For some reason the ui doesn't get updated until a reboot (didn't test logoff/login).
Maybe there is some other command line tool that does the change and ensures that the UI gets updated as well.

btw: I used the following command to get the files that changed recently (only checked /var and ~ so far):

```
sudo find /var -newermt "-1 minute" -ls
```

There aren't any changes to gsettings. I monitored the settings using this command:

```
dconf watch /
```

Comment: Thanks for the information. I verified that the same file is updated for me and it is. I haven't tried to actually add it to my dotfiles script yet.

Comment: `/var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager-intern.conf` is internal, it should not be modified, as the code comment there says. If you'd like to edit the setting via config-files, the it's best to put a snippet to `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d`. Alternatively, use D-Bus `busctl --system set-property org.freedesktop.NetworkManager /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager org.freedesktop.NetworkManager ConnectivityCheckEnabled "b" 1` which indeed will write the configuration to the internal file.

Comment: Thanks @thaller for the command, but you should replace `1` by `0` to disable the connectivity check

Answer (score 6):

I just wanted to add that you can also disable the connectivity checking by simply creating an empty file:

```
sudo touch /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf
```

This file will override any settings found in `/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf`.

Comment: I just tried this on a new Ubuntu 18.10 installation and the connectivity option disappeared completely from the Settings -> Privacy tab. I suppose that means it is off ;)